# What is the maximum current that can pass through my pcb?

Tags: pcb, high-current

As I been learning electronics I been creating custom PCBs instead of using solderable breadboard like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082LYLQSL).

On my design I am planing to turn on and off a motor with a a relay that uses **12 volts @ 15 amps. (180 Watts).** My PCB looks like this:

[image]

The thick (0.11 inches of width) blue pads is where I plan to pass 15 amps of current. That is the reason why I made them extra thick. **Will it be safe to use this thick pads @ 180 watts?** Where can I find a rule that states how thik the pads are and how much current they can use?

### Edit

I should had done more research sorry. Your comments answer the question. I need 2 oz of copper when building my pcb. That increases the price by more than double though. I will solder cables on the back of the pcb instead of using 2 oz of copper as I am only using one relay in my whole PCB. **The blue thick pads will also have wires soldered on the back** I will just have to solder 3 cables.

Comment: Check this out https://www.7pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.php

Comment: What did your own research turn up by now? Did you look into https://www.google.com/search?q=current+capacity+pcb or similar? According to this source you wont like the result: https://www.mclpcb.com/pcb-trace-width-vs-current-table/ . But this is for 1oz Copper only. The current capacity strongly depends on the copper thickness. However the solder junctions are mostlikely our even bigger problem in this scenario. What type of relay you are planing to use anyway?

Comment: I am planning to use this relay: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Relays_Ningbo-Songle-Relay-SRA-05VDC-CL_C99666.html

Comment: Work towards making the conductor cross area the same as the relay pins and always observe the derating for reactive loads

Comment: Provided there is nothing on the other side of the board you can also create traces running from the other side, possibly also stitch the two with vias to further decrease the path resistance. Also, is this supposed to be a permanent 180W or just peak?

Comment: It runs @ 180 watts for 10 seconds and then it stops.